# How to keep aspect ratio in panel C#?

Tags: c#

I save an image in preview mode. Preview mode contains `Picturebox and Label` control.

The problem is when I save an image. Likely I recorded my screen.

The export image is different with my expect, it does not keep aspect ratio. 
So, all control in panel after save to example.jpg will wrong position.

My code use to ScaleImage:

```
public static Image ScaleImage(Image image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    var ratioX = (double) maxWidth/image.Width;
    var ratioY = (double) maxHeight/image.Height;
    var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

    var newWidth = (int) (image.Width*ratio);
    var newHeight = (int) (image.Height*ratio);

    var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
    Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    return newImage;
}
```

My code save image:

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
string s = lstImgAdded.Items[k].Text;
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(@"" + s);
panel2.BackgroundImage = bm;
PointF p1 = StretchImageSize(postPoint, panel2);
g.DrawImage(
    DrawText(lstAliasImage[i - valuesFrom], fontType, colorInput,
        Color.Transparent),
    Point.Round(StretchImageSize(postPoint, panel2))); // Point.Round(StretchImageSize(postPoint, panel2)) ở đây dùng nhìu lần

g.DrawImage(ctrl.Image, Point.Round(StretchImageSize(postPointPicturebox, panel2)).X, Point.Round(StretchImageSize(postPointPicturebox, panel2)).Y,
    ctrl.Width, ctrl.Height); // panel2 có phải cái hình nhỏ ko? ko. picturebox moi la nho, panel la background lon


g.Dispose();
string linkLocation = txtAddress.Text;
ScaleImage(img, witdhImg, heightImg)
    .Save(linkLocation + "\\" + lstAliasImage[i - valuesFrom] + "." + imgType,
        ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

And class `StretchImage` to scale `control(Picturebox, Label)` with `a panel`.
Image show before image in a panel is different after save.

[image: Image in my software]

In my software, Image shown in the panel. It does not scale like in `Preview software`:
[image: After in save in my computer]

Comment: I just wish I understood it...

Comment: Can you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Post the complete code for writing the image and text.

Comment: I was post complete code for writing the image and text.

Answer (score 0):

**Applying Aspect Ratio to Windows Forms**

```
Much like we intercepted Windows message in our Windows 7 Style Form, to keep the aspect ratio of a Windows Form we are going to intercept the resizing Windows messages. This is done by overriding WndProc.

Here is a list of the constants that we need for this algorithm:

WM_SIZING = 0x214
WMSZ_LEFT = 1
WMSZ_RIGHT = 2
WMSZ_TOP = 3
WMSZ_BOTTOM = 6
```

1. The first one is the way our C# application can tell when the Form
   is being resized. The rest of the constants tell us exactly which
   side of the Form is being resized. Note that for corners the edges
   combine. So for example, the lower left corner would be resizing the
   right and bottom parts of the form and thus be 2 + 6 = 8.
2. The advantage of using WndProc instead of Windows Form events is
   that we can prevent the Form from flickering. Resize events in .NET
   are called until after the resizing has been applied, so modifying
   size in an event produces flickering.
3. Make sure to download the sample C# application. Notice how no
   matter where you resize the Form from, the aspect ratio is
   maintained. A quick peek at the source code shows how either the
   height or width is adjusted depending on which side of the Form was
   being resized. Another cool thing is that the Form can still be
   maximized to fill the entire screen without any problems.

try this

```
public void ResizeImage(string OriginalFile, string NewFile, int NewWidth, int MaxHeight, bool OnlyResizeIfWider)
{
System.Drawing.Image FullsizeImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(OriginalFile);
// Prevent using images internal thumbnail
FullsizeImage.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
FullsizeImage.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
if (OnlyResizeIfWider)
{
if (FullsizeImage.Width  MaxHeight)
{
// Resize with height instead
NewWidth = FullsizeImage.Width * MaxHeight / FullsizeImage.Height;
NewHeight = MaxHeight;
}
System.Drawing.Image NewImage = FullsizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(NewWidth, NewHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);
// Clear handle to original file so that we can overwrite it if necessary
FullsizeImage.Dispose();
// Save resized picture
NewImage.Save(NewFile);
}
```

Comment: I was check in this link: `http://www.vcskicks.com/maintain-aspect-ratio.php` and use your class. `WndProc` override winform. But I don't know using in panel.

Comment: call this methods in panel resize event

Comment: `OriginalFile` is path link to an image? And `NewFile` is path link to folder create an image.I don't know any parameter.

Comment: Can your help me? I checked your answer but not run in my project.